# make faust agent wait for other agents to finish

Tags: faust

Is there any way to make faust agent run when some other agents finish?
For example

```
       Agent1
       +
       |
       |
       |
Agent2 +------------->Agent_final
       |
       |
       |
       +
       Agent3
```

`Agent_final` should start when all `Agent1,Agent2,Agent3` finish. And `Agent_final` should have access to all 3 agents output.
Didn't find this common approach in docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a couple things. You could make it more linear:

```
A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> AF
```

Or you could have AF do a join. The way I've done this is:

- have the parent agents all write to the same topic, so in this case `(A1,A2,A3)` would all write to `agent_final's_topic`.
- `agent_final` keeps a Table that looks like `{id: {A1: x, A2: y, A3: z}}`. `x`, `y`, and `z` are either None or whatever the parent agents produce.
- When `agent_final` reads a message, it checks the Table for the id, adds the value to the correct field (corresponding to the agent the message is from)
- If all 3 fields are not `None` then all three contributing Agents have finished, so you can now do whatever it is `final_agent` was meant to do.
- If there are any missing fields, you can save the updated dict back to the table, and then move on to the next message without doing anything else.

Shameless plug:

I made a library to do this kind of processing ([github](https://github.com/BWStearns/faust_joins), [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/faust-joins/)). Sink all the dependency messages to one topic, write a key, merge, and sufficiency function and follow the instructions in the README to use it to block processing until multiple upstream agents do their thing.